# How to align View vertically to the text inside TextView?

Tags: android, textview, imageview, android-constraintlayout, autoresize

I'm trying to achieve this result:

[image: Expected result]

What I have right now it is `ConstraintLayout` which includes three `Views`: `TextView`, `ImageView`, `ImageView`

Design requirements:

1. Text centered inside `TextView`;
2. `TextView` has fixed size 80dp
3. Size of text should be AutoSizeable;
4. **`ImageViews` should change position horizontally depending on text position inside `TextView`**. See images with case #1/#2 for reference.

***Is it possible to achieve item 4 in XML?*** What about programmatically?

**[Additional info]**

Autosizing doesn't work properly with width `wrap_content`, see [autosizing documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview):

> Note: If you set autosizing in an XML file, it is not recommended to use the value "wrap_content" for the `layout_width` or `layout_height` attributes of a [TextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html). It may produce unexpected results.

Comment: You answered your own question which is great. It looks like you applied the bounty after answering your question. If that's right, what about your answer are you not satisfied with?

Comment: My solution works well, but I'm not sure about efficiency. And I wanna get more views and opinions on that. We have such simple thing like `layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf` to align views horizontally. 
But what about vertically? Maybe in some future, it will be added :)  
What is the best way to do it? @Cheticamp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So after an investigation found two solutions for this:

- Calculation of text width and applying a horizontal bias to `ImageView`s;
- Custom text view - `AutoResizeTextView`;

In the **first case**, we get actual `width` of text in the `TextView`:

```
Rect bounds = new Rect();
textView.getPaint().getTextBounds(textView.getText().toString(), 0, textView.getText().length(), bounds);
float width = bounds.width();
```

And then apply simple math to calculate `horizontal bias` for `ImageView`s.

**Second option** is to add custom view. It is differ from [autosizing-textview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview) . It will resize text after measuring in `onLayout`. And in `onTextChanged` we reset text size without resizing. Ellipsizing it's an additional feature which may be useful in some cases.

```
/**
 * Text view that auto adjusts text size to fit within the view.
 * If the text size equals the minimum text size and still does not
 * fit, append with an ellipsis.
 */
public class AutoResizeTextView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView {

    // Minimum text size for this text view
    public static final float MIN_TEXT_SIZE = 20;

    // Interface for resize notifications
    public interface OnTextResizeListener {
        public void onTextResize(TextView textView, float oldSize, float newSize);
    }

    // Our ellipse string
    private static final String mEllipsis = "...";

    // Registered resize listener
    private OnTextResizeListener mTextResizeListener;

    // Flag for text and/or size changes to force a resize
    private boolean mNeedsResize = false;

    // Text size that is set from code. This acts as a starting point for resizing
    private float mTextSize;

    // Temporary upper bounds on the starting text size
    private float mMaxTextSize = 0;

    // Lower bounds for text size
    private float mMinTextSize = MIN_TEXT_SIZE;

    // Text view line spacing multiplier
    private float mSpacingMult = 1.0f;

    // Text view additional line spacing
    private float mSpacingAdd = 0.0f;

    // Add ellipsis to text that overflows at the smallest text size
    private boolean mAddEllipsis = true;

    // Default constructor override
    public AutoResizeTextView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    // Default constructor when inflating from XML file
    public AutoResizeTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    // Default constructor override
    public AutoResizeTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        mTextSize = getTextSize();
    }

    /**
     * When text changes, set the force resize flag to true and reset the text size.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onTextChanged(final CharSequence text, final int start, final int before, final int after) {
        mNeedsResize = true;
        // Since this view may be reused, it is good to reset the text size
        resetTextSize();
    }

    /**
     * If the text view size changed, set the force resize flag to true
     */
    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        if (w != oldw || h != oldh) {
            mNeedsResize = true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Register listener to receive resize notifications
     *
     * @param listener
     */
    public void setOnResizeListener(AutoResizeTextView.OnTextResizeListener listener) {
        mTextResizeListener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * Override the set text size to update our internal reference values
     */
    @Override
    public void setTextSize(float size) {
        super.setTextSize(size);
        mTextSize = getTextSize();
    }

    /**
     * Override the set text size to update our internal reference values
     */
    @Override
    public void setTextSize(int unit, float size) {
        super.setTextSize(unit, size);
        mTextSize = getTextSize();
    }

    /**
     * Override the set line spacing to update our internal reference values
     */
    @Override
    public void setLineSpacing(float add, float mult) {
        super.setLineSpacing(add, mult);
        mSpacingMult = mult;
        mSpacingAdd = add;
    }

    /**
     * Set the upper text size limit and invalidate the view
     *
     * @param maxTextSize
     */
    public void setMaxTextSize(float maxTextSize) {
        mMaxTextSize = maxTextSize;
        requestLayout();
        invalidate();
    }

    /**
     * Return upper text size limit
     *
     * @return
     */
    public float getMaxTextSize() {
        return mMaxTextSize;
    }

    /**
     * Set the lower text size limit and invalidate the view
     *
     * @param minTextSize
     */
    public void setMinTextSize(float minTextSize) {
        mMinTextSize = minTextSize;
        requestLayout();
        invalidate();
    }

    /**
     * Return lower text size limit
     *
     * @return
     */
    public float getMinTextSize() {
        return mMinTextSize;
    }

    /**
     * Set flag to add ellipsis to text that overflows at the smallest text size
     *
     * @param addEllipsis
     */
    public void setAddEllipsis(boolean addEllipsis) {
        mAddEllipsis = addEllipsis;
    }

    /**
     * Return flag to add ellipsis to text that overflows at the smallest text size
     *
     * @return
     */
    public boolean getAddEllipsis() {
        return mAddEllipsis;
    }

    /**
     * Reset the text to the original size
     */
    public void resetTextSize() {
        if (mTextSize > 0) {
            super.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, mTextSize);
            mMaxTextSize = mTextSize;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Resize text after measuring
     */
    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        if (changed || mNeedsResize) {
            int widthLimit = (right - left) - getCompoundPaddingLeft() - getCompoundPaddingRight();
            int heightLimit = (bottom - top) - getCompoundPaddingBottom() - getCompoundPaddingTop();
            resizeText(widthLimit, heightLimit);
        }
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    }

    /**
     * Resize the text size with default width and height
     */
    public void resizeText() {
        int heightLimit = getHeight() - getPaddingBottom() - getPaddingTop();
        int widthLimit = getWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();
        resizeText(widthLimit, heightLimit);
    }

    /**
     * Resize the text size with specified width and height
     *
     * @param width
     * @param height
     */
    public void resizeText(int width, int height) {
        CharSequence text = getText();
        // Do not resize if the view does not have dimensions or there is no text
        if (text == null || text.length() == 0 || height <= 0 || width <= 0 || mTextSize == 0) {
            return;
        }

        if (getTransformationMethod() != null) {
            text = getTransformationMethod().getTransformation(text, this);
        }

        // Get the text view's paint object
        TextPaint textPaint = getPaint();

        // Store the current text size
        float oldTextSize = textPaint.getTextSize();
        // If there is a max text size set, use the lesser of that and the default text size
        float targetTextSize = mMaxTextSize > 0 ? Math.min(mTextSize, mMaxTextSize) : mTextSize;

        // Get the required text height
        int textHeight = getTextHeight(text, textPaint, width, targetTextSize);

        // Until we either fit within our text view or we had reached our min text size, incrementally try smaller sizes
        while (textHeight > height && targetTextSize > mMinTextSize) {
            targetTextSize = Math.max(targetTextSize - 2, mMinTextSize);
            textHeight = getTextHeight(text, textPaint, width, targetTextSize);
        }

        // If we had reached our minimum text size and still don't fit, append an ellipsis
        if (mAddEllipsis && targetTextSize == mMinTextSize && textHeight > height) {
            // Draw using a static layout
            // modified: use a copy of TextPaint for measuring
            TextPaint paint = new TextPaint(textPaint);
            // Draw using a static layout
            StaticLayout layout = new StaticLayout(text, paint, width, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, mSpacingMult, mSpacingAdd, false);
            // Check that we have a least one line of rendered text
            if (layout.getLineCount() > 0) {
                // Since the line at the specific vertical position would be cut off,
                // we must trim up to the previous line
                int lastLine = layout.getLineForVertical(height) - 1;
                // If the text would not even fit on a single line, clear it
                if (lastLine < 0) {
                    setText("");
                }
                // Otherwise, trim to the previous line and add an ellipsis
                else {
                    int start = layout.getLineStart(lastLine);
                    int end = layout.getLineEnd(lastLine);
                    float lineWidth = layout.getLineWidth(lastLine);
                    float ellipseWidth = textPaint.measureText(mEllipsis);

                    // Trim characters off until we have enough room to draw the ellipsis
                    while (width < lineWidth + ellipseWidth) {
                        lineWidth = textPaint.measureText(text.subSequence(start, --end + 1).toString());
                    }
                    setText(text.subSequence(0, end) + mEllipsis);
                }
            }
        }

        // Some devices try to auto adjust line spacing, so force default line spacing
        // and invalidate the layout as a side effect
        setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, targetTextSize);
        setLineSpacing(mSpacingAdd, mSpacingMult);

        // Notify the listener if registered
        if (mTextResizeListener != null) {
            mTextResizeListener.onTextResize(this, oldTextSize, targetTextSize);
        }

        // Reset force resize flag
        mNeedsResize = false;
    }

    // Set the text size of the text paint object and use a static layout to render text off screen before measuring
    private int getTextHeight(CharSequence source, TextPaint paint, int width, float textSize) {
        // modified: make a copy of the original TextPaint object for measuring
        // (apparently the object gets modified while measuring, see also the
        // docs for TextView.getPaint() (which states to access it read-only)
        TextPaint paintCopy = new TextPaint(paint);
        // Update the text paint object
        paintCopy.setTextSize(textSize);
        // Measure using a static layout
        StaticLayout layout = new StaticLayout(source, paintCopy, width, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, mSpacingMult, mSpacingAdd, true);
        return layout.getHeight();
    }
}
```

Source of the code above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5535672 by [Chase](https://stackoverflow.com/users/210130/chase), who quoted Sam Hocevar.

Answer (score 2):

Playing around with some set values for sizing that you can adjust to suit your app, I achieved this look using xml alone.

The images a gammy, I cut them from you original image. I've utilised the constraint layout and a relative layout. The text responds to resizing and rotation.

A vertical view

[image]

A horizontal view

[image]

Small text

[image]

Large text

[image]

Of course play around with the sizing to suit your needs.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.yvettecolomb.myapplication.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">


    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/ll1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:text="TEST"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_margin="-10dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tv1"
            android:src="@drawable/a"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv1"
            android:src="@drawable/b"/>


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_margin="-10dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tv2"
            android:src="@drawable/c"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:text="test test test test test"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv2"
            android:src="@drawable/d"/>
    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use AppCompatTextView. Change autoSizeMaxTextSize, autoSizeMinTextSize and autoSizeStepGranularity values.

```
                    <RelativeLayout
                    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:id="@+id/rl_flashcard_back"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_text"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="16sp"
                        app:autoSizeMinTextSize="8sp"
                        app:autoSizeStepGranularity="1sp"
                        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                        />

android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView tv_text = mRootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_text);
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview